# Minimal framework to render a mobile website into an App

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I have a mobile version of my website and I want to make it available as an app, is there a very simple framework for that? I just need to wrap it in a browser window, make some local storing of data and have access to some basic phone features like notifications.. I took a look into phonegap but it seems to use some mobile specific frameworks, I just rather use what I am using now for my mobile website, which is pretty much html5, css3 and regular jquery (not mobile).

I am not sure this is the best place to ask for tech recommendation, if not, please tell me where could I post it on stackexchange network and I will delete the question and post there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All cordova does is rap your Html/Css/Js while you can add plugins to it to enable the use of device Native features using Javascript. So cordova will be just fine.

Alternatively you can you use the Crosswalk Embedding project which is (code based) a Chromium browser with even more API features than the mobile Chrome browser. One downside is that because its a full browser it's also around 19 megs added on top of the App.

[Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/)

[Embedding Crosswalk Android](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html)

[Embedding Crosswalk IOS](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/ios/embedding_mode_&_native_apis.html)